# How do I add Control-A as a Hotkey to all EDITTEXT controls in a dialog box?

Tags: winapi, dialog

I have a bunch of dialog boxes created with `DialogBox()` from definitions in a resource file. The dialog boxes have a bunch of controls created with `EDITTEXT` statements (and some others).

I have noticed that <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> does not work as a hotkey for selecting all text. How do I add it?

"Select All" appears in the popup context menu, and works correctly if chosen by mouse.

Comment: "*I cannot use a manifest because I am in a DLL, and DLLs do not have manifests*" - actually, a DLL *can* have a manifest. But that is not the solution to your problem

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Do I want to know how DialogBox knows which DLL manifest to look at to find which version of the common controls library to resolve registered window classes to?

Comment: An EXE's manifest is defined in resource ID 1, and a DLL's manifest is defined in resource ID 2. Windows APIs know to look at those two resources depending on which kind of module a window belongs to. And if you have a dialog template in a DLL, you have to tell `DialogBox()` which DLL to pull it from, so it knows which DLL to look for resource ID 2 in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit controls don't support <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> natively (even though they have this command in their context menu).

If you want to add <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> handling to an edit control you can do it through sub-classing.

For example,

```
LRESULT CALLBACK CtrlASubProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    if (uMsg == WM_DESTROY)
        RemoveWindowSubclass(hWnd, CtrlASubProc, uIdSubclass);
    else if (uMsg == WM_GETDLGCODE && wParam == 'A')
    {
        if (GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) < 0)
            return DLGC_WANTALLKEYS | DLGC_WANTMESSAGE;
    }
    else if (uMsg == WM_CHAR && wParam == 1) // ctrl-A
    {
        SendMessage(hWnd, EM_SETSEL, 0, -1);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}


void AddCtrlAHandlingToEditControl(HWND hwndEdit)
{
    SetWindowSubclass(hwndEdit, CtrlASubProc, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Menu is the edit control's context menu. Most likely, you have still posted the right answer, although I think I will have to do EnumWindows to grab all the edit boxes.

Comment: @Joshua If there's more than one control then yes, use `EnumChildWindows` and then `GetWindowClass` to identify `EDIT` controls. Presumably the `WM_COMMAND` handler sends the `EM_SETSEL` message to the control that currently has input focus.

Comment: @JonathanPotter The Edit control owns the context menu it displays. The menu would send `WM_COMMAND` to its owner window, not the window that has input focus.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ah I missed that it was a context menu, thought the OP was talking about a window menu